# CoreData AppDelegate - ERROR

Tags: swift, core-data

Estou encontrando erro ao criar a variável context
"There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
O erro retornado é no persistentStoreCoordinator do AppDelegate.swift

```
@IBAction func salvarButton(sender: UIButton) {
    let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate 
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext


let newUser = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Pessoa", inManagedObjectContext: context)
newUser.setValue(nomeText.text, forKey: "nome")
newUser.setValue(Int(idadeText.text!), forKey: "idade")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema apareceu depois que modifiquei o banco de dados..
Foi resolvido o problema reiniciando o Simulador,
no menu do Simulador -> Reset Content and Settings